# Can connect to server through ssh via terminal, but login times out through nautilus

Tags: networking, server, ssh, nautilus, sftp

I'm trying to connect to my university's server through `ssh`. In the terminal, I type `ssh hostname` and it connects after a while (it does take some time, but it connects). I am not typing my username, for my username in the server is the same as in my local computer.

However, I am not able to connect to the server through Nautilus. If I go to "Other Locations" and try to connect to the server by typing `sftp://hostname` (or `sftp://user@hostname`, for the matter), the connection fails and I receive a warning stating "Unable to access location - Timed out when logging in".

Can I change Nautilus' login timeout limit? If so, how?

I am aware there are similar questions to this on the internet, and even on the website, but I was not able to use their suggestions to fix my problem. I know very little about ssh connection or how I can configure it.

Comment: `ssh` connection should not take more than a few seconds time. You can use `ssh -v hostname` on command line (verbose mode) to figure out at which stage your ssh client is spending most of the time during session establishment, and try to resolve the problem.

Comment: Your university server admin may have configured it to allow interactive ssh access but not sftp. Does it work if you try `sftp -v user@hostname` from the command line?